# What is a quick way to access Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to switch from Firefox to Chrome, so trying to get up to speed with the interface.

I have installed some Chrome extensions such as World Clock.

To access it I have to:

- Click `Wrench`
- Click `Tools`
- Click `Extensions`
- On World Clock, click `Options`
- Click `Save`

and then I can use it.

What am I missing here, there must be an easier way.

Is there a way to just click something and have all my extensions in a dropdown, i.e. in one click?

I couldn't find this on a [list of chrome hotkeys](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650).

Comment: ok, I found a simpler way: (1) CTRL-T for new tab which shows all my apps, (2) click "world clock".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a browser button, right click it and  hit manage extensions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a keyword as a shortcut to the extensions panel.

1. **Right-click** on the omnibar and select **Edit Search engines**
2. Add a search engine with the values  **xtn** / **xtn** / **chrome://extensions/** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Once you have created a shortcut you can use it like a web address in the url bar.
To open the Chrome extensions panel type **ext** in the omnibar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This can be done to allow easy access to any of the internal Chrome functions. 
This command: **`chrome://chrome-urls`** lists all Chrome internal URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way for me is:

1. Open Chrome.
2. In the address bar at the top, type chrome://apps.
3. Press Enter.
4. Click the app you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this natively in the Chrome browser, especially since the source you're quoting from is Google.

However, like minded individuals think alike, and someone else who was thinking like you came up with a Chrome Extension that will let you set shortcut keys, called the [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf).

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first few steps in your process by browsing to the URL, [chrome://extensions/](http://chrome://extensions/)

You could also place a bookmark for the extensions on your bookmark toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

**Least keypresses**

**<kbd>ALT</kbd> ; <kbd>ENTER</kbd> ; <kbd>L</kbd> ; <kbd>ENTER</kbd> ; <kbd>E</kbd> ; <kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

Even less keypresses if you automate this with software like [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/).

**Least mouse clicks**

Create a bookmark to `chrome://extensions/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an additional extension! One-click Extensions Manager
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E4%B8%80%E9%94%AE%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E6%89%80%E6%9C%89%E6%89%A9%E5%B1%95/niemebbfnfbjfojajlmnbiikmcpjkkja

Comment: Please add more details about what this extension does.

Answer (score 0):

Kranu's answer above got me on the right track.  As of 3/2015 .. the solution for me was to:

1. Right click on on bookmarks bar
2. Enable "Show Apps Shortcut" - Adds rainbow grid to left side of bookmarks bar
3. Click the Apps Shortcut icon and Extensions are now there for direct access